# Getting get params within post request using params hash

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

There is a code in Sinatra application

```
post '/login' do
  return_url = params[:return_url] # it's nil
  #........
end
```

The url of a page might contain `return_url` parameter - `/my_app/login?return_url='blabla'`. When I try to get it, it returns nil because there is no `return_url` parameter in post data.

How do I access to get `params` of `return_url`? I know I might create a hidden field and save it to it, but is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is translated into params for a GET request. Since you're referring to a POST request, I assume you already have a form on the page that will translate to params in your sinatra post action. In this case, the query string is ignored.

You can add a hidden field to the form as you suggest. You could also store the return_url in the user's session when they load the form prior to logging in. It could be something like:

```
enable :sessions

get '/login_form' do
  session[:return_url] = 'blahblah'
end

post '/login' do
  return_url = session.delete(:return_url)
  # login
end
```